Error in OpenSIPS When Modifying Route Header to Remove Commas in BYE Method
I am working with OpenSIPS 3.1 and trying to modify the Route header in SIP messages for the BYE method. My goal is to remove all commas present in the Route header if the BYE message originates from a specific IP address.
Context:
I want to prioritize handling INVITE messages.
If the method is BYE and it comes from a specific IP address, I need to modify the Route header by removing the commas and then relay the message.
I am using append_hf to add the modified header.
Current Code:
route[sequential_request] {
    if (has_totag()) {
        if (loose_route()) {
            route(fix_to_header);
            if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                record_route();
                route(relay);
                exit;
            } else if (is_method("BYE") && $si == "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX") {
                xlog("Received BYE request from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\n");
                if (is_present_hf("Route")) {
                    xlog("Original Route header: $hdr(Route)\n");

                    # Modify the Route header by removing all commas
                    append_hf("Route: $(hdr(Route){s/,//g})\r\n");

                xlog("Modified Route header: $(hdr(Route){s/,//g})\n");
            }
            route(relay);
            exit;
        }
        route(relay);
    } else {
        if (is_method("ACK")) {
            if (t_check_trans()) {
                route(relay);
            } else {
                sl_send_reply(404, "Not Here");
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            sl_send_reply(404, "Not Here");
            exit;
        }
    }
} else {
    if (is_method("INVITE")) {
        trace("tid", "d", "sip|xlog");
    } else if (!is_method("CANCEL")) {
        trace("tid", "t", "sip|xlog");
    }
}

}

Problem:
When trying to run this code, I get the following error:
Aug 19 06:01:44 sippy1 OpenSIPS_3.1[655]: Aug 19 06:01:44 [1] ERROR:core:parse_transformation: invalid transformation: {s/,//g} ())! Aug 19 06:01:44 sippy1 OpenSIPS_3.1[655]: Aug 19 06:01:44 [1] ERROR:core:parse_transformation: error parsing [{s/,//}] Specific Questions:
What is the correct way to modify the Route header to remove commas?
Are there any recommended alternatives for handling this type of modification in OpenSIPS?
How can I improve the logic of my script to ensure the Route header is processed correctly?
What I Already Know:
I understand that the function isn't correct, and the transformation I'm attempting isn't supported.
I have reviewed the sipmsgops module documentation but haven't found a clear way to handle comma removal in the Route header.
Any advice or solutions on how to correctly modify the Route header in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
This version is more detailed and clarifies that you're aware the function isn't working as intended and are seeking guidance on how to approach the problem correctly.
